# Remote access applications showing a blank window for a single app

Tags: windows, remote-control

I am trying to remotely access my Windows 10 box in order to manage my 3D printer.

To do so, I usually use  [chrome remote desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en), but with the 3D printer software I only see a blank window. I tried with teamviewer, but again, blank window with the 3D printing software.

Said software is available [here](https://www.tiertime.com/downloads/software), if anybody wants to try if the issue is repeatable.

To be extremely clear, what is happening is that I can access my box with CRD or TV without any issue, I can use any application **except** UP Studio, linked above. I do not have a screenshot at hand, but the effect is that the window is present, I can move and resize it, and close it, and even click it, but the content of the window is completely white.

It looks to me that this is some sort of graphic issue, and something that the application provider should solve, as all the rest on my machine is working fine.

I have written to customer support and currently waiting for feedback, which I will dutifully post, but I am wondering on how is this even possible, and if there is something I can try to do to make this work.

Comment: Please note that [this](https://superuser.com/questions/777492/teamviewer-other-screen-sharing-showing-a-blank-or-black-screen-to-remote-user) looks like a duplicate, but it's not. In the other question teamviewer does not work _at all_, while for me it does not work for a single app.

Comment: Does the application run as administrator? I doubt that is an issue here, but depending on how you installed your remote apps it could be. Can you right-click and run as administrator on any OTHER software and see the screen properly?

Comment: This is a very interesting insight, I will try as soon as I have physical access to my box.

Comment: This is something to test accessing the computer remotely.

Comment: I am sorry, yeah, what I meant is that I need to turn it on, and then try remotely of course :)